# Loading image and text using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

Here i am trying to run a code to take in an image and resize it and then to open it using a tkinter frame with a a text along with it.

```
root2 = Tk. Tk()
filename = "pichart.png"
basewidth = 500
img = Image.open(filename)
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
os.remove(filename) # deletes the original image after you have got the resized image
img.save('pichart.png')
bard = Image.open("pichart.png")
bardejov = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bard)
label1 = Tk.Label(root2,image=bardejov)
label1.image = bardejov
label1.place(x=20, y=20)
samp="sfaagdgaegadgadfasasdasda"
label2 = Label(root2, text=samp)
label2.place(x=600, y=20)
root2.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (1400, 700, 00, 00))
root2.mainloop()
```

The image gets converted and saved but while displaying ,it comes up with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\Mainproject\Best final backup - Copy\sentimentsummarizer.py", line 611, in     <module>
      label1 = Tk.Label(root2,image=bardejov)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2475, in __init__
     Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
     File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1974, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
    TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist
```

though running the display snippet alone works fine with image in the direectory.

Comment: the error message and your code do not correspond to each other (code uses `pichart.png`, the traceback mentions `pyimage10`). See [code example that implements slideshow in Tkinter](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c)

Comment: that is the problem i too was thinking about , i may be some lirary image. not sure

Comment: try to replace: `label1.image` with `label1.configure(image=bardejob)` as in my code

Comment: `pyimage10` is simply the name used internally to represent the image stored in the variable bardejob

Comment: The code you posted works for me after I add the missing imports. We can't help you if you don't show us the actual code that produces the error.